# How to avoid ModuleNotFoundError when run unittest discover?

Tags: python, python-unittest

The unittest file imports the module from its root directory and runs the file directly without any problems; however, when running the test in its upper directory using discovery mode, a ModuleNotFoundError occurs.

Of course the easiest solution would be to move that module to the root directory where the tests are run, but because I often need to run the test software directly, so this is not OK.

It is possible to create a copy, but it violates the DRY rules and is prone to various naming conflicts, which is not an elegant solution.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

```
├──TheTest_0     
│  ├──__init__.py
│  ├──meta_test.py
│  ├──mydict.py
├──runTest.ps1
```

```
python -m unittest discover --start-directory .\ --pattern "meta_test.py"
```

```
    from mydict import Dict
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mydict'
```

Comment: set the PYTHONPATH=TheTest_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two lines of code at the top of the test file to solve the problem.

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Thanks @drum！